# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, service

I can access web service on my iis by IE. But when I want to access web service by emulator,it raises No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I am using VS 2008.Emulator can access internet. I updated my web referance as localhost or http://127.0.0.1/ but it doesnt work. Anonymus access is enabled on web service and I dont use proxy server.What can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 (a.k.a. localhost) means "the machine holding the current socket."  If you're on the emulator, that translates to "connect to the emulator itself", so basically you're attempting to connect to a web server *on the emullator* not the PC that's hosting it (it's a VM, so they are effectively two distinctly separate machines) and that's failing for obvious reasons.

Use the PC's IP address or hostname.

Comment: yes, u are right.But after i wrote ip adress,it says  "Unable to read data from the transport connection."Do u have any idea what can cause that error?

Comment: Without knowing how you have your connection set up (e.g. is it a paassthrough connection?) it's difficult to say.

Comment: Having same problem. I still could not access my PC's localhost using the windows mobile emulator although I can access external websites through the internet. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The last time I saw this was because the server didn't have its actual IP.  I don't believe the emulator isn't going to have access to the computer's 127.0.0.1 address.  Have you tried using the actual IP address?

Comment: yes, u are right.But after i wrote ip adress,it says  "Unable to read data from the transport connection."Do u have any idea what can cause that error?